# Are leftshift and OR operators commutative in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Example:

```
Operation 1:
d= c | y | z | a<<3 | b <<3 | x;

Operation 2:
m = c|y|z|x;
d = m | a<<3 | b<<3;
```

does operation 1 and operation 2 yield same results in C?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: In this case, it should provide the same results since (a) there are no side effects, and (b) the `<<` operator has higher precedence than `|`. It's not a question of commutativity, but a question of precedence between operators.

Comment: @mbratch I feel your comment would be a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question in your title:

> **Are leftshift and OR operators commutative in C?**

the `|` bitwise-or operator is commutative, but the `<<` operator is not (`a<<3` and `3<<a` are quite different).

That doesn't appear to be what you meant to ask, though. To answer the body of your question, since `<<` has higher precedence than `|` (i.e., `<<` binds more tightly), you can think of `a<<3` and `b<<3` as if they were primary or parenthesized expressions. In effect, you have multiple subexpressions joined by `|` operators. Rearranging them should have no effect; your two code snippets should behave identically (except that the second one stores a value in `m`, which doesn't exist in your first snippet).

This assumes that all the variables you're using are of the same type. If they're not, then storing the intermediate value in `m` might involve a conversion which could alter the results. This probably doesn't apply in your case, but since you didn't show us any declarations it's impossible to be sure of that.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it should provide the same results since (a) there are no side effects (*e.g.* built-in pre- or post-increments or decrements), and (b) the `<<` operator has higher precedence than `|`.

So, the `<<` operations will occur before the `|` operations.

It's not a question of commutativity, but a question of precedence between operators. Although it does help that `|` itself is commutative since your choices do change the order in which expressions are or'ed together.